# getAsync() not working in Office Add-In for Outlook on mac

Tags: office-js

I am trying to obtain the email text from a compose screen in my add-in for Outlook for Mac. I have the code set up in a UI-less button that appears in the Compose screen. The add-in loads correctly (the button appears in the Compose screen), but nothing happens when I click the add-in button.

Here's my code:

```
function scanText(event) {
  try {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function(text) { 
      if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      } else {
        console.log('quando');
        event.completed();
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    showError(err);
    event.completed();
  }
}
```

I expect 'quando' to be printed in the console, but I don't see anything in the Vorlon console. What am I missing? I don't think it's a requirements issue, as the [Requirements](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook) page states that Outlook 2016 for Mac supports all sets:

[image]

But what else could it be?

Some other background information:

- I set up Vorlon using [these instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2016/02/18/vorlonjs-plugin-for-debugging-office-addin/)
- I am hosting the web server locally, and have set up my system to accept the self-signed certificate.
- I am running on Outlook for Mac v15.40 (171108), on Exchange 2013 SP1.

Comment: What do you get out of `showError(err)`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur It's a function that prints a short (hardcoded) error message to the console. I don't see that message, either.

Comment: Are you sure the `scanText` function is being fired at all?

Comment: Can you check if the function is being called? If the function is not getting called try updating the function name in your manifest 

<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
 <FunctionName>scanText</FunctionName>
</Action>

Comment: I have double checked that my manifest contains the function name. However, I am unable to determine if the function is being called (or not); this is why I am printing a debug statement to begin with. Is there another way of checking if the function is called?

Comment: I found a problem with my code that prevents me from seeing if `scanText` is being executed. Turns out, the entire function-file.js file is wrapped inside an anonymous function; removing the wrapping and changing the body of `scanText()` to just a single `console.log()` command confirms that the method does indeed get executed (via console output). Interestingly, if I also include `event.completed()` in `scanText()`, I would not see the console output.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have "text" as parameter in your callback while you are checking result with "asyncResult" in if condition. You might be get error as asyncResult undefined if you start to work in strict mode.

Just replace text from callback with asyncResult. Also, log error in if condition, to know if asyncResult status is failed.